# Samba issues - seems to be working, nothing can connect

Tags: server, samba

Ubuntu 18.04LTS
Samba version 4.7.6-ubuntu

Issue: Win 10 and Android devices can see the share, but when I connect I get an error, the most helpful of which is that in ESFile explorer on Android:
Login fails
This may be cause by:
-list of items, most likely is blocked by the firewall

I have added the credentials specifically to the client side and I've also even reset the Samba password for that user as the same as the machines user (in case).
the change I made to /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[development]
comment = Samba on Tietokone
path = /home/chris/sambashare
read only = no
browsable = yes
```

permissions of that directory:

```
chris@tietokone:~$ ls -ld samabashare/
drwxrwxr-x 2 chris sambashare 4096 Feb 10 09:11 samabashare/
```

also, from one of the logs

```
[2020/02/11 09:09:52.786410,  0] ../source3/smbd/service.c:774(make_connection_snum)
  canonicalize_connect_path failed for service development, path /home/chris/sambashare
```

Thanks for any suggestions

PS: sudo smbstatus shows that its 4.7.6-Ubuntu, and also shows connection attempts

```
Samba version 4.7.6-Ubuntu
PID     Username     Group        Machine                                   Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15253   chris        chris        jcifs0_1_2e (ipv4:192.168.43.202:50750)   NT1               -                    -                    

Service      pid     Machine       Connected at                     Encryption   Signing     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

/home/chris is drwxrwxr-x
/home/chris/sambashare is the same

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious: Are you connecting from the client as "chris"? If not: Is your home directory encrypted? What are the permissions of /home/chris? If for example /home/chris has a mode of 700 and I try to connect as morbius and provide the correct samba password, samba will let me in but from my perspective there is no /home/chris/sambashare path.

Comment: >Are you connecting from the client as "chris"?

Yes

I won't be able to answer the other question until later in the week because I left my laptop at home.